# Get the digit of last page in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

How do I get just the last page number, not the link that comes with $this->Paginator->last(), but the actual digit itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-a-page-counter) will help you to achieve the same.

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->counter('{:pages}');
     //counter() method with all options
     //echo $this->Paginator->counter('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}');?>
```

You can call the counter() method into your view to get the last page number.

Comment: I needed not :end but :pages which works. So I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
echo $this->Paginator->param('pageCount');
```